# Excel: Sort table on one sheet sum up on the next

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet on a document that has all of the sponsorship donations that my team has received, and the name of the company that gave them to us. I want to take this information and sort the information and sum up the donations.

The information in the first spreadsheet is in a table with three columns, Name of the company, amount of the donation, date of donation.

For instance Spreadsheet one contains:

- Company1 | $5000 | 5/10/12
- Company2 | $6300 | 6/12/10
- Compnay1 | $750  | 8/9/11
- Company3 | $6800 | 6/17/10
- Compnay2 | $3000 | 8/29/12

I would like spreadsheet two to be:

- Compnay1 | $5700
- Compnay2 | $9300
- Compnay3 | $6800

How would I get this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, but the most flexible is the pivot table:

- Select a cell of your spreadsheet one,
- Insert Pivot Table
- put the company as a row field and the amount as a data field
- Right-click the data field and Format the number.
- You're done already.

If you put the data in spreadsheet 1 in an excel table (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), you can use the name of the table as the data source for the pivot, so it extends with the table (just right-click and refresh the pivot when the data changes).